# How to solve a fraction with a numerator in exponential form and a denominator in numerical form without a calculator?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation, number-systems, mental-arithmetic, scientific-notation

The question:

"Imagine unwinding (straightening out) all of the DNA from a single typical cell and laying it "end-to-end"; then the sum total length will be approximately $2$ meters. Assume the human body has $10^{14}$ cells containing DNA. How many times would the sum total length of DNA in your body wrap around the equator of the earth."

The Earth's equator is $40,075$ km

Now I got this question right by dividing the assumed total length of DNA by the distance of the equator:

$$\frac{10^{14} \cdot 2 \ m}{40,075,000 \ m} = 4,990,642$$

The answer key says the answer to the question is "about $5 * 10^6$ times around the equator". But my question is, can I solve this question with an equation that converts the distance of the equator to exponential form to arrive at the same formatted answer as the answer key? Is there a mnemonic that makes it simple to do in your head? For example, if I used the equation:

$$\frac{10^{14} \cdot 2}{10^7 \cdot 4}$$

Then solved that equation to this:

$$\frac{10^7 \cdot 2}{4}$$

From here is it possible to get $$10^6 \cdot 5$$ (the answer) without using a calculator?

Comment: $\frac{10^7 \cdot 2}{4} = \frac{10^7}{2} = \frac{10}{2}\cdot 10^6 = \ ?$

Comment: Btw, for what *good* reason was that question down-voted?

Comment: Just a reminder on the rules of our site: if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) consistently in your post, and tag your questions appropriately, people are less likely to downvote your question on first glance.

Comment: The first thing to do, if you are doing it mentally, is get rid of the excess precision.  The earth's equator is $40,000$ km, not $40,075$.  The error is $0.2\%$.  Mental calculation is usually less precise than slide rules (do you remember those?  I do).  For most cases a few percent error is fine, often ten percent, and even within a factor of two or five can be useful.  You ought to have an idea how good your number is.

Comment: google "scientific notation".  I think that is *exactly* what you are asking about

Comment: $\frac 24 = \frac 12 = 0.5 = \frac 5{10}$.  So $\frac {10^7\times 2}4= \frac 24\times 10^7=\frac 5{10}\times 10^7= 5\times \frac {10^7}{10}= 5\times 10^6$.  Its just a matter of keeping track of decimal points. Before calculators it was a basic counting skill all students were expected to know.  Practice it.  In a little while (less than 2 days I predict) you will be able to do much harder problems in your head.

Comment: "Btw, for what good reason was that question down-voted?"  No good reason I can tell. This was a creative and well thought out question which is *exactly* what we want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For your simpler example, $\frac{2 \cdot 10^7}{4}$, rewrite $10^7 $ as $10^1 \cdot 10^6 = 10 \cdot 10^6$. Then you have $\frac{20 \cdot 10^6}{4} = 5 \cdot 10^6$.

Now back to the original question: $$\frac{2  \cdot 10^{14}}{40,075,000}$$

First, convert the denominator to standard form (scientific notation), which is $4.0075 \cdot 10^7$. Then rewrite the numerator as $20 \cdot 10^{13}$ using the same process as before.

Then you have:
$$\frac{20  \cdot 10^{13}}{4.0075 \cdot 10^7}$$

where you can now estimate the denominator as $4 \cdot 10^7$ since you will not lose any precision, except if you are using more than $3$ sig figs. Then use the laws of indices to calculate this expression (which one is it)?

Answer (score 3):

You have to recognize that $10=2 \cdot 5$, so $\frac{10 \cdot 2}4=5$.  You can borrow a $10$ from the $10^7$ by subtracting $1$ from the exponent.

Mental arithmetic, like so many skills, rewards practice.  Depending on the calculations you want to do, it also rewards having facts memorized so they are *easy*.  Do you see $1001$ and immediately think $7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13?$  Or $1000(1+0.1\%)?$  For calculations like this, approximations are acceptable.  I answered an earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415092/question-for-mathematicians-who-started-before-the-computer-era-what-constants/415126#415126) with the types of things I have at my fingertips.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about scientific notation.

$40,075 $kilometers is $40,075,000$ meters.  And $40,075,000=4.0075\times 10^7$.

And the dna being $2$ meters times $10^{14}$ is $2\times 10^4$.

So you want to solve $\frac {2\times 10^{14}}{4.0075 \times 10^7}=$

$\frac {2}{4.0075}\times 10^{14-7}\approx$

$\frac 12 \times 10^{7}=$

$0.5 \times 10^{7}=$

$0.5 \times 10 \times 10^6$

$5 \times 10^{6}$.

Why did I round $\frac 2{4.0075}$ to $\frac 12$?

The degree of accuracy of "about" $2$ meters, makes the accuracy of the equater of the earth far more accurate then is necessary.  The molecule is *not* $2$ meters long it is *about* $2$ meters long and the degree of error will be greater than $75$ kilometers.

Note: this is *not* being lazy or inaccurate.  It would actually be *wrong* and inaccurate to include the $75$ kilometers.

====

Anyhoo.... scientific notation is *all* about these type of multiplication and division problem of numbers of extreme scale.

Any number can be written, within some degree of accuracy, as as a single ones value decimal times $10$ to some power.  So to multiply or divide you deal with just the ones value decimals and add or subrtact the tens power.

Example if hair grows at $5$ inches a year, how fast does it grow in miles per hour.

Well there are $12$ inches in a foot and $3$ feet in a yard and $1760$ yards in a mile so there are $12\times 3\times 1760$ inches in a mile.

$12=1.2\times 10^1$ and $3 = 3.0\times 10^0$ and $1760=1.8\times 10^3$ (that's as accurate as we need) so there are $1.2\times 3\times 1.8\times 10^{1+0+3}=6.48\times 10^4\approx 6.5 10^4$ inches in a mile.

And there are $24$ hours in a day, and $364.5$ days in a year so $2.4\times 10^1 \times 3.645\times 10^2 \approx 2.5\times 3.5 \times 10^3=8.75 \times 10^4$ hours in a year.

so $5 \frac {inches}{year} = 5\frac {\frac 1{6.5 10^4} miles}{8.75\times 10^4 hours}=$

$\frac {5}{6.5\times 8.75 \times 10^{4+4}}=$

$\frac {5}{56.875 \times 10^8}\approx$

$\frac {5}{57\times 10^8}\approx \frac 1{11}\times 10^{-8}\approx$

$0.90909090.... \times 10^{-8}\approx$

$0.91 \times 10^{-8}= 9.1\times 10^{-9}$.

So hair grows approximately $9$ billionths of a mile per hour.